# how to add image footer on dynamic html page with different content size in print without overlaping main contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create a html printable report. For that I have added image as a footer on my html page. Here contents of the page are not fixed. I tried different media css and javascript liberary like  `printjs.crabbly.com` , `jquery.PrintArea.js` but couldn't get success. Whenever I print my report footer image  overlapping main contents.
the problem is  I couldn't add page-break-* css  explicitly at appropriate location since contents of the page are not fixed.

```
@media {

footer{
        position:fixed;
        width: 100%;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        display:block;
        height: 100px;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-after: always;
     }
```

Even I tried to use @page css to fixed margin but footer is scrolling with main contents.

Footer image:

[image]

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: do you use javascript or jQuery on the page?

Comment: I am not using javascript or jquery on the page . I  was  trying to use javascript and jquery to resolve my issue.